# Devise before_action not working, allowing bypass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem occurring. I am trying to not let the users view other posts, threads (pins) by setting a method 'correct user' as shown below and a before action for devise at the top. However, when I log on as a user and try to bypass it works and I am able to edit, destroy. It is not redirecting to pins_path.

Not even an error is occurring, so it is really hard to decipher what is going on. I'll post the code from the controller and please ask if you need to see anymore. Thanks.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end


  def show
  end


  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
  @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end



  def update
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
      else
        render action: 'edit'
      end
    end




  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

  def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not allowed!" if @pin.nil?
  end


def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
end
end
```

Comment: How come you aren't doing `current_user.pins.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: I tried that, but it was still bypassing.

Comment: You are checking whether the user is *correct* before you've even authenticated the user... put `correct_user` *after* `authenticate_user`... There may be more than one bug here, but you at the least need to do that (because otherwise `current_user` will be empty) :) (you should probably put `authenticate_user` as the very first filter)

Comment: It also looks like a pin belongs_to a user. You can check if `@pin.user == current_user` or `pin.user_id == current_user.id`. This way you can just take the @pin you were setting in the other before rather than query another select.